# RestHighLevelClient Elastic Search Java Client takes more time for Search Query

Tags: elasticsearch

RestHighLevelClient is taking more time for Search Queries and have bad performance.From direct Elastic Search Rest API it is taking less time.
How can we optimise the performance for this search request

This is the Code Snippet :

```
SearchRequest searchRequest=new SearchRequest(new String[] 
              {indexName},searchSourceBuilder);
 
 searchSourceBuilder.trackTotalHits(true);

 searchResponse =restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Query created using BoolQueryBuilder:

```
      {
      "size": 100,
      "query": {
      "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "from": "2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "to": "2017-08-30T00:00:00.000Z",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
      }
      },
      "sort": [
      {
      "date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
      },
      {
      "id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
      }
      ]

      }
```

Comment: What are you measuring? What are the execution times? How much data are you fetching? What do you do with the data?

Comment: can you also add your query which you directly generating and time for both queries?